# Conditional statement not working in Angular ngIf

Tags: angular

I am working on sample project in which i am using GET request to fetch the data from API and storing it array . And using that array i am creating radio buttons.

**Example**

**Array**

```
[
{
active: 0
categoryId: 8
categoryName: "ItemCustomerType"
codeName: "All"
description: "Type"
globalCodeId: 5
},
{
active: 0
categoryId: 8
categoryName: "ItemCustomerType"
codeName: "Agent"
description: "Type"
globalCodeId: 21
},
{
active: 0
categoryId: 8
categoryName: "ItemCustomerType"
codeName: "Private"
description: "Type"
globalCodeId: 22
}
]
```

Now i want to show only those radio buttons whose **"codeName" value = Private or"codeName" value = Agent**

**Code for Radio Button**

```
                    <label class="radioBtn" *ngFor="let customerCodeName of itemSourceData;let i = index">{{customerCodeName.codeName}}
                      <input type="radio" value="{{customerCodeName.codeName}}"
                             (change)="onChangeItemSource(customerCodeName.codeName)" formControlName="itemType">
                      <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
```

**here itemSourceData contains the data fetched from API in form of array. But the PROBLEM is it is showing 3 radio buttons for codeName :'All','Agent','Private' but it should show only 2 radio buttons for **'Agent' and 'Private'** only  **.

**Any solution please ?**

Answer (score 1):

Filter your list for your loop.

```
let list = itemSourceData.filter(i=>i.codeName==='Private'||i.codeName==='Agent');
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add an if statement in your input type to only add radio buttons if it is `Private` or `Agent` inside for loop.

HTML

```
<label class="radioBtn" *ngFor="let customerCodeName of itemSourceData; let i = index"
  >{{ customerCodeName.codeName }}
  <input
    *ngIf="
      customerCodeName.codeName === 'Private' || customerCodeName.codeName === 'Agent'
    "
    type="radio"
    value="{{ customerCodeName.codeName }}"
    (change)="onChangeItemSource(customerCodeName.codeName)"
    formControlName="itemType"
  />
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```